# Singleton with custom init body

Tags: swift, singleton

I would like to create a class singleton with custom body of private method but I get a following message error for the line: `static let sharedInstance = AppBundle()`

> Missing argument for parameter 'rawValue' in call

Code

```
class AppBundle {

    static let sharedInstance = AppBundle()

    enum AppBundle: String {
        case developer
        case alpha
        case beta
        case appStore
    }


    let appBundle: AppBundle = .appStore

    private init() {
        if let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
            switch bundleIdentifier {
            case "com.app.developer":
                self.appBundle = .developer
            case "com.app.beta":
                self.appBundle = .beta
            case "com.app.alpha":
                self.appBundle = .alpha
            default:
                self.appBundle = .appStore
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't declare an `enum` and a `class` with the same name, the compiler cannot decide which one you are trying to instantiate, it thinks that `static let sharedInstance = AppBundle()` here `AppBundle` refers to the `enum`.

You should rename your `enum` to make it have a different name than your class.

There were also some other issues in your code. Namely, you cannot give a default value to `appBundle` if you want to declare it immutable with the `let` keyword. I have change the `init` method to work with the implementation without a default value and declaring `appBundle` immutable.

```
class AppBundle {

    static let sharedInstance = AppBundle()

    enum AppBundleType: String {
        case developer
        case alpha
        case beta
        case appStore
    }


    let appBundle: AppBundleType

    private init() {
        if let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
            switch bundleIdentifier {
            case "com.app.developer":
                self.appBundle = .developer
            case "com.app.beta":
                self.appBundle = .beta
            case "com.app.alpha":
                self.appBundle = .alpha
            default:
                self.appBundle = .appStore
            }
        } else {
            self.appBundle = .appStore
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

enum AppBundle is set to type String.

You need to provide raw string values for all your cases for example :

```
enum AppBundle: String {
        case developer = "dev"
        case alpha = "alpha"
        case beta = "beta"
        case appStore = "appStore"
    }
```

Comment: The compiler can make rawValue on its own for such simple cases, that's not the issue.